# ListView listing the key in hashmap as list items and displaying the value of hash map as WebView

Tags: android, listview, servlets, webview

I have JsonArray of object sent by servlet to android client.

```
Eg: {"PDF":    [{"pdf":"resume.pdf","html":"http://localhost:8080/Files/Sample/resume.html"},{"pdf":"profile.pdf","html":"http://localhost:8080/Files/Sample/profile.html"}]}.
```

In this example I'am having pdf and html as key. At client end Iam parsing it through json object and listing the value of "pdf" as list items in listview, I mean resume.pdf first item, and profile.pdf as second item.

Now when i click on resume.pdf then corresponding html should open in web view. I coded till listing the items, but facing confusion as how to pass the url as intent to another activity to start WebView.

This is my OnCreate method where on item click listener is enabled...

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String html;
// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://ipaddress/LoginValidation/LoginCredentials";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_FILES = "PDF";
private static final String TAG_PDF = "pdf";
private static final String TAG_HTML = "html";
// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray pdftohtml = null;
ListView lv;
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fileList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    fileList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    lv = getListView();
    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
```

**//What to write to get only corresponding html value of pdf file**

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HtmlWebViewActivity.class);
            //in.putExtra(TAG_HTML,);

            startActivity(in);

        }

    });

    new GetFiles().execute();

}
```

This is my Async Task

```
private class GetFiles AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                pdftohtml = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FILES);
                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < pdftohtml.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = pdftohtml.getJSONObject(i);
                    String pdf = c.getString(TAG_PDF);
                    html=c.getString(TAG_HTML);
                    HashMap<String, String> file = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    file.put(TAG_PDF, pdf);
                    file.put(TAG_HTML, html);
                    fileList.add(file);
                }
                System.out.println("TAG PDF"+TAG_PDF);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                fileList, R.layout.listitem, new String[] { TAG_PDF }, new int[] {
                        R.id.pdf });
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

As you can see in my Async task iam using json to parse the response and getting the "pdf" and "html" key values in filellist(arraylist) , then in post execute using adapter displaying only "pdf" values as list item. Now how to get the corresponding "html" values in ItemClickListener in **OnCreateMethod**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your first activity you would launch the activity like this:

**Pseudo Code**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyWebViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("URL", url);
startActivity(i);
```

then in the WebViewActivity you would look for the extra in `onCreate` like so:

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");
```

**EDIT**

Start by creating a separate class for your data model:

```
public class ResumeResultObject{
     public String pdf;
     public String html;
     private static final String TAG_PDF = "pdf";
     private static final String TAG_HTML = "html";

     public ResumeResultObject(JSONObject obj){
           pdf = obj.getString(TAG_PDF);
           html = obj.getString(TAG_HTML);
     }
}
```

*you could make that above class parcelable if you wanted to be able to pass it along as a whole object*

I'd change the array list to be:

```
ArrayList<ResumeResultObject> fileList;
```

I would also create an adapter for your listView:

```
public class ResumeListViewAdapter extends 
ArrayAdapter<ResumeResultObject>{


    final static int layoutResId = R.layout.some_xml_layout //for each list item; 

    private Context context;
    final ArrayList<ResumeResultObject> mArrayList;

    String pdf = null;
    String html = null;

    public ResumeListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ResumeResultObject> objects) {
        super(context, layoutResId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        mArrayList = objects;
        //callback = (OnSwipeLeftDismissListener) context;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final View view = convertView == null ? View.inflate(context,
                layoutResId, null) : convertView;

       // handle how you want to display each one here
    //something like: 
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label)).setText(mArrayList.get(position).pdf);

        return view;
    }


}
```

in your Async task i would move all the parsing out of doInBackground.  if there is an error right now in the response you are probably going to crash, because it appears that you are not handling any response errors.. but in you postExecute you can take the result (post checking for any errors) and pass it back to a method in your main class..

```
public void handleResult(JSONObject obj){
            fileList = new ArrayList<ResumeResultObject>();

            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                    ResumeResultObject r = new ResumeResultObject(c);
                    fileList.add(r)
            }
            ResumeListViewAdapter myAdapter = new ReseumeListViewAdapter(this,fileList);
            lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

finally in your main activity:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            ResumeResultObject selected = fileList.get(position);

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HtmlWebViewActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("URL",selected.html);
            startActivity(in);

        }
```

Comment: I know this basic code, but i need something different, above i have edited my code , could you please refeer it and give me some suggestions

Comment: I would not set the list adapter in onCreate personally.  I would wait for the result.  I would also create a DataModel class that has a constructor that takes a json object. and set my array list to that type.. i'll edit my answer above

Comment: the above edits i made are technically just pseudo code.. i didn't test it and since stack doesn't offer code hinting (travesty) and i have not had coffee yet there could be some errors, but should get you going if i understand your question

Comment: Thank you so much erik, for your wonderful reply, the code which you prefered is so logical and loose coupled, i prefer your code. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            **String urlvalue=fileList.get(position).get(TAG_HTML);**
            System.out.println("HTML URL Value"+urlvalue);

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HtmlWebViewActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("URL",urlvalue);
            startActivity(in);

        }
```